# QGridLayout, expand widget on the line

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a QGridLayout to handle my widgets. The fact is they stay in the column I put them, without expanding on the whole width. Is there any option to tell the rows to expand completely ? The goal would be to mimic the behavior of a QHBoxLayout, but without using one.

Example:

```
self.label_player = QtGui.QLabel("Chemin du lecteur :")
self.line_path = QtGui.QLineEdit()
self.button_select_player = QtGui.QPushButton("Sélectionner")

...Some code

self.grid_settings.addWidget(self.label_player, 3, 0, 2, 1)
self.grid_settings.addWidget(self.line_path, 3, 1, 1, 1)
self.grid_settings.addWidget(self.button_select_player, 3, 2, 1, 1)
```

EDIT:

Here is an image of what I want, I obtained the result with a QHBoxLayout in the QGridLayout, for the line in red (what I try to do without):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Nced.png

And here is one with the default behavior of the QGridLayout. It's what I currently have:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDlkK.png

Comment: Add the code where you create your layout and add widget, so we can see what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Done. I added a code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        big_one = QtGui.QPushButton('Big one')
        big_one.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.grid.addWidget(big_one, 0, 0, 2, 2)
        self.grid.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton('Ajouter'), 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton('Enlever'), 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel("Chemin du lecteur :"), 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(QtGui.QLineEdit(), 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton("Selectionner"), 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(QtGui.QCheckBox("Some long text in french"), 3, 0, 1, 3)
        self.grid.addWidget(QtGui.QCheckBox("An even longer text in french than the first one"), 4, 0, 1, 3)
        self.grid.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel("Something, something, something"), 5, 0, 1, 2)
        self.grid.addWidget(QtGui.QSpinBox(), 5, 2, 1, 1)
        self.setLayout(self.grid)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = Window()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Yes, but you don't answer the question. I can use it, in the exact same way as you do.

But what I would like is to set the grid in a way the widgets would take all the width, on each line. Here for example, my lineEdit stays in its column, and there is an huge space between the label and the lineEdit.
Almost like if I'd put the widgets in a QHBox, and the QHbox then in the grid, on one line.

Comment: I don't understand you at all, can you attach an image to the question of what it looks like on your machine and how you want it to look like. If I see the image, I would know how to answer you. This is just poking in the dark.

Comment: You're right. I edited again the first post. I don't know if what I want to do is possible. I think so. I can obviously reach what I want, but the window will become more complicated, and it'll become harder to manage the code with QHBoxes.

Comment: @user1585507 Updated the answer. Not **exactly** as you wanted, but pretty close.

Comment: Yes, you changed the spanning (and you noticed I'm french :)). But I would like to extend your approach to all the widgets, buttons included. I'm sure it is possible, otherwise it would be too complicated to maintain a complex window with QHBoxes.

Comment: @user1585507 For that you need to set the sizePolicy of the Widget, updated the example again using button. HBoxLayout, and VBoxLayout change the Size policy of their widgets.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, it was more a matter of spanning, you were right since a while. I built your code and fund some errors in the coordinates and the spanning, especially for the spin box. But the sizePolicy is also a useful tip.